# A limit ordinal $\gamma$ is indecomposable if and only if $\alpha + \gamma = \gamma$ if and only if $\gamma = \omega^{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I am trying to prove ex 2.13 from Jech's book on set theory:

> Ex 2.13: A limit ordinal $\gamma$ is indecomposable if and only if $\alpha + \gamma = \gamma$ if and only if $\gamma = \omega^{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$.

I think this is equivalent to proving that the 3 following statement are equivalent:

1. $\gamma$ is indecomposable (i.e. there are no $\alpha,\beta < \gamma$ s.t. $\gamma = \alpha + \beta$).
2. For every $\alpha < \gamma$, $\alpha + \gamma = \gamma$.
3. There exists $\alpha$ s.t. $\gamma = \omega^{\alpha}$.

I think that I can prove $(1) \rightarrow (3)$ since it seems almost straight forward from Cantor's normal form theorem. I can also prove that $(1) \Rightarrow (2)$ since, for every $\alpha < \gamma$, there exists a unigue $\delta$ s.t. $\alpha + \delta = \gamma$. Given, (1), $\delta \geq \gamma$. But $\delta > \gamma \Rightarrow \alpha + \delta > \gamma$ and we are left with $\delta = \gamma$.

My problem is with the other directions. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

For $(2) \rightarrow (3)$ assume that $\gamma$ can't be written as
$\omega^\alpha$.  Then by Cantor's normal form theorem $\gamma =
\omega^{\beta_1}\cdot k_1 + \dots + \omega^{\beta_n}\cdot k_n$ with
$k_1 > 1$ or $n>1$.  But then $\omega^{\beta_1} < \gamma$ and
also
$$\begin{align*}
\omega^{\beta_1} + \gamma = \omega^{\beta_1} + (\omega^{\beta_1}\cdot k_1 + \dots + \omega^{\beta_n}\cdot k_n)
&= (\omega^{\beta_1} + \omega^{\beta_1}\cdot k_1) + \dots + \omega^{\beta_n}\cdot k_n\\
&= \omega^{\beta_1}\cdot (k_1+1) + \dots + \omega^{\beta_n}\cdot k_n\\
&> \omega^{\beta_1}\cdot k_1 + \dots + \omega^{\beta_n}\cdot k_n
= \gamma
\end{align*}$$
which together contradicts $(2)$.

For $(3) \rightarrow (1)$ let $\beta_1,\beta_2<\gamma=\omega^\alpha$.
By Cantor's normal form theorem you'll easily find $\alpha'<\alpha$
and $k\in\omega$ with $\beta_1,\beta_2<\omega^{\alpha'}\cdot k$.  This
implies $\beta_1 + \beta_2 < \omega^{\alpha'}\cdot (k+k) <
\omega^\alpha=\gamma$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Most of it I understood. Exapt one thing: In $(2) \rightarrow (3)$, at the end of the proof, how do we get that $\omega^{\beta_1} + \gamma > \gamma$?

Comment: In $\omega^{\beta_1}+\gamma$ write $\gamma$ as $\omega^{\beta_1}\cdot k_1 + \dots + \omega^{\beta_n}\cdot k_n$, then the sum is $\omega^{\beta_1}\cdot (k_1+1) + \dots + \omega^{\beta_n}\cdot k_n$.

Comment: I've extended my answer to hopefully clarify this issue.

Comment: Why does $\beta_1 + \beta_2 < \omega^{\alpha'}\cdot (k+k)$ follow?

Comment: $\beta_1+\beta_2<\omega^{\alpha'}\cdot k+\omega^{\alpha'}\cdot k=\omega^{\alpha'}\cdot (k+k)$