# if $\alpha<\beta$ then $\omega^\alpha+\omega^{\beta}=\omega^{\beta}$

Tags: proof-writing, induction, set-theory, ordinals

Prove that if $\alpha<\beta$ then $\omega^{\alpha}+\omega^{\beta}=\omega^{\beta}$

Proof: I'm not too sure what to start with to attempt this, I was thinking that I would need to perform transfinite induction either $\alpha$ or $\beta$ but i'm not sure, if someone could give me some direction on what to do that would be great.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2347786/ordinals-of-the-form-alpha-omega-alpha

Comment: I don't see which part of that question is related.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933450/a-limit-ordinal-gamma-is-indecomposable-if-and-only-if-alpha-gamma-ga), on the other hand, is much more relevant, though.

Comment: @Gibberish: You are asking for a direction to start. I thought you could find some starting point from that problem. Also there is a link given as a comment which is closely related to your problem.

Comment: @Bumblebee oh okay thank you for the contribution. The post that is more relevant uses cantors normal form, which i haven't been taught yet so i was wondering if there is an approach that does not require this?

Comment: Have you followed on the duplicate of the "more relevant" link I gave? There you can find suggestions for approaches which do not use Cantor Normal Form.

Comment: Assume w^a +w^b contains w^b +1. Arrive at a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Consider ordinals as well-ordered sets in the usual way.
As $\omega^\beta\ge\omega^{\alpha+1}$ then $\omega^\beta$
has an initial segment order-isomorphic to $\omega^{\alpha+1}$.
Removing this gives a well-ordered set, order-isomorphic to an ordinal
$\gamma$, so
$$\omega^\beta=\omega^{\alpha+1}+\gamma.$$
Thus it suffices to prove that $\omega^{\alpha+1}=\omega^\alpha
+\omega^{\alpha+1}$. But $\omega^{\alpha+1}$ is order-isomorphic
to a $\omega^\alpha$ concatenated with itself "$\omega$" times
(the lexicographic product of $\omega^\alpha$ with $\omega$).
Adding an extra $\omega^\alpha$ at the front won't change this
order type, so indeed $\omega^\alpha+\omega^{\alpha+1}
=\omega^{\alpha+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** : There is $\delta >0$ such that $\alpha + \delta = \beta$, so that $\omega^\alpha + \omega^\beta = \omega^\alpha + \omega^\alpha \omega^\delta = ...$

Comment: This is a hint, not an answer.

Comment: @Alephnull : there is the word "Hint" in boldface indeed..